# Did Reza Shah Pehlavi know about Turkish offer to restore Ahmad Shah Qajar?

Tags: persia, turkey, iran, 1920s, coup

Ahmad Shah Qajar, Shah of Persia was deposed in a military coup by Colonel Reza Khan in 1921 and was subsequently exiled.

While he was in exile, Kemal Ataturk summoned the Persian ambassador Anoushirvan Sepahbody and sent a message to the deposed Shah, offering to restore him to the throne.

> "The Turkish government, in pursuance of its own national interest and
>   for reasons of friendship, goodwill, and a desire to assist Your
>   Majesty, is willing to extend a formal invitation to Your Majesty, to
>   travel to Turkey and hence, to offer the help of a sufficient number
>   of Turkish troops for Your Majesty to be able to enter Persia from the
>   West and regain his throne."

The deposed Shah thanked Ataturk but refused to accept the offer.

After that, Turkish Government recognized Reza Khan (Now Reza Shah) as the legitimate Shah of Persia and formed friendly relations with the new regime.

So my question is, Did Reza Shah Pehlavi know of Turkish offer to Ahmad Shah Qajar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the date of this offer, an explanation could be made to why Reza Khan, future Palavi, did not take into account the offer of Ataturk as an agression.

The putsch made by Reza Khan in 1921 did not immediately led to the destitution of the Shah, this one being officially made [in 1925](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmad_Chah_Qadjar).
Another point is that the former shah of Iran, in the end of 19th century, tried very hard to get closer to European countries and their way of life. For example, in 1925, Ahmad Shah Qajar went to France and lived there until his death.

So the answer is: "Real politic". More precisely, Reza Khan knows he has a military support, but need internal and international recognitions. When Ataturk propose military forces to restore Ahmad Shah Qajar, he is using the circumstanes to get stronger relationship with Persia. Considering that the offer was declined, what is left to Ataturk, in difficulty with European countries after its multiple wars (against the French in Cilicia and the Greeks in Western Turkey), is to create new links with the new dynasty of Shah. On the other hand, Reza Khan, becoming Palavi, has no interest in fighting Turkey (on diplomacy or with war).

To conclude, at that time many diplomatic offers were made in secret, but in any case Turkey and new Shah of Persia had both advantages in hiding this fact in their relationship.

Comment: @CGCampbell Until the death of Ahmad Shah Qajar of course